# Not enough reputation for comment, should new users write answers instead?

Tags: discussion, comments

I have a comment on [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/8178/3775) which might be helpful, but definitely not a complete answer.

I would write that comment, but do not have enough reputation yet to do that. Should I write my comment in an answer instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Try to flesh it out into a complete answer first, *then* post it.

Failing that, answer a few other questions to gain the [comment everywhere](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) privilege, and then post a comment.

(You've already done the latter, but I'm answering for the benefit of others who might share this question)

Comment: Yep, just got it :) ...I guess I found it a little difficult at first to gain the required reputation for commenting everywhere. But I guess that's something everyone has to go though =)